# jQuery: I need to show consecutive fields in a form at each new click

Tags: jquery

I have 5 upload fields but I need to hide them except the first. Then at each click to show them one by one.

I created the following script but it seems like item.show() is not displaying the hidden fields.10x

```
first = $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').first();
    first.after('<a id="addmore" href=#>[+] Add more</a>');
    $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            first.show();
    });

    var c = 1;//counter
    $('#addmore').bind('click', function(e) {
        item = $('edit-submitted-file'+c+'-ajax-wrapper');
        item.show();
        ++c;
    if (c == 5) {
      $('#addmore').hide();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Are you only going to have 10 uploads available? I ask because if so it would be much easier to have them already on the dom and just do a simple show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't this:

```
var item = $('edit-submitted-file'+c+'-ajax-wrapper');
```

be

```
var item = $('#edit-submitted-file'+c+'-ajax-wrapper'); //if using id
or
var item = $('.edit-submitted-file'+c+'-ajax-wrapper'); //if using class
```

Comment: Thanks.I also tried without luck this$('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').each(function(){
              console.log($(this));
              if($('div#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper') == $(this)){
                  $(this).show();
              }

Comment: it should be also be var item = $('edit-submitted-file'+c+'-ajax-wrapper'); otherwise IE8 will popup an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend `'#'` to the selector for `-ajax-wrapper` because you are selecting it by ID.

The counter needs to start at 2 and hide addmore on 6.  The `return false` (should actually be `e.preventDefault()` should be outside of that conditional.

`addmore` should be added after the last of the file input rows, not the first.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the first element is 4 or other number

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `next()` function and `:visible` selector

Example:

**HTML**

```
<label><span>File</span> <input type="file" /></label>
<label><span>File</span> <input type="file" /></label>
<label><span>File</span> <input type="file" /></label>
...
```

**JQuery**

```
$('label:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all except the first one
$('label:visible').click($(this).next('label').show()); // show the following
```

`:visible` is not necessary, as you can't click on hidden elements, but it's just an optimisation.